# SQL statement too long in VBA

Tags: sql, vba

In order to have the completed SQL i stored it at one of the worksheets then extract from there, but having error if the statement too long as the vba not able to capturing the full SQL code (if the filter data is not alot it works fine). Im very new to use the SQL in the VBA and hope if there any way can solve for this

Please refer below code that i have created, Thanks. It will stop at the Commandtext = Array(SQLCODE) when requested too many data. Thanks

```
CODE1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6")

SQLCODE = CODE1
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "ODBC;DSN=EBT-RAW;UID=00174;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2016;WSID=SNG-LP-0153;DATABASE=EBTRawConsumption" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array(SQLCODE)
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_EBT_RAW"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

This is SQLCODE

```
Select * FROM EBTRawConsumption.dbo.AMI_UsageData 
WHERE UsageDate >= '2019-6-1'and UsageDate <= '2019-7-1'
and MeterID in ('','000572992','000674117','000685835','000680646','000681342','000697973','000697890','000728193','000728213','000730270','000730266','000730800','000730267','000732442','000731276','000730869','000731890','000731592','000735403','000737161','000737976','000739532','000738001','000737581','000737596','000737996','000738298','000737587','000738840','000739370','000739367','000736241','000737089','000738970','000740763','000742172','000746989','000750232','000749300','000749303','000749179')
```

Comment: Can you try `.CommandText = SQLCODE`?

Comment: It's possible you just have too many items in your IN() clause.  Yu could try switching to ADO and see if that helps.  Would help to mention how many id's there are when it fails.

Comment: Hi all, it works! Many thanks